# Proper function naming and import in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I've developed a project with a package/module/function structure that resembles this one:

```
project/
│--mainfunc.py
|
└───functions/
    │--__init__.py
    |--func_caller.py
    │
    ├───subfolder1/
    │   │--__init__.py
    │   │--func11.py
    │   │--func12.py
    │
    └───subfolder2/
        │--__init__.py
        |--func21.py
        |--func22.py
```

Each of the `funcXX.py` modules contains a Python function inside, named e.g.:

```
# /project/functions/subfolder1/func11.py

def do_func11(args):
    # Do something
    return some_value
```

The `func_caller.py` file calls the functions defined in each of the `funcXX.py` modules one at a time. The top section of `func_caller.py` (where all the imports are) looks like:

```
from subfolder1.func11 import do_func11 as df11
from subfolder1.func11 import do_func12 as df12
from subfolder2.func21 import do_func21 as df21
from subfolder2.func22 import do_func22 as df22
```

This seems an unnecessarily complicated way to do this. I though of naming the functions inside each `funcXX.py` module simply `main()`, so as to be able to import them with:

```
import subfolder2.func22 as df22
```

but this results in:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are splitting all your functions up into separate modules? I would group your functions together into relevant modules. For example, put all the functions that relate to database management into one module, etc.  That way, you can call `from subfolder1.func import do_func11, do_func12, do_func21` as appropriate.

Comment: Each module (ie: `funcXX`) already contains several functions grouped by relevance. Usually I just have to call  a single function inside each module (ie: `do_funcXX`), and that one calls all the others.

Comment: Just to clarify this old question: We are missing the line which produces the error message. It does not make sense to shorten the function names to `df21` etc. as you do. Maybe you were looking for a plugin architecture which imports modules and executes their entry points automatically? --- Possible simple solution (not plugin architecture): **1.** Naming the modules' main functions / entry points `main()` is OK. **2.** Import the modules this way: `from subfolder1 import func11` **3.** Call the module's function this way: `func11.main()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from subfolder2.func22 import name_of_func
```

Comment: That works, but it just removes the `as xxxx` part. I'd like to do something simpler/shorter like: `import subfolder2.func22 as f22`.

Comment: From subfolder2.func22 import name_of_func as f22

Comment: If you look at the question, you'll see that is exactly the way I'm doing it right now, which I want to shorten.

Comment: I suggest putting all of your functions into a single module and import the module with the functions you need.